# Subversion merge loops over the same revision

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Using Subversion plugin in Eclipse Juno, am trying to merge 80+ revisions from branch B to A. The point is that, some revisions were already merged manually. But there is no reference tells which revisions were merged manually, so, I decided to merge all 80+ revisions.

After merging each revision, SVN prompts me with current conflicts to resolve, I do resolve them by hand, then mark the file as resolved. Every thing is happy so far.

But when I mark all conflicts as resolved, SVN should try to merge the next revision and so on, but it merges the **same revision** again and again, showing the same conflicts and I resolve them again, it loops infinitely this way.

I figured out that, this happens only with revisions which were manually merged earlier. And could not find any online talk about this issue. Any help?

Comment: Did you try to commit after a finished merge and befor merge next one?

Comment: Didn't tried that as it will take so long time. It worked anyway when used eclipse Luna

Answer (score -1):

I tried to do the same thing with Eclipse Luna and it worked as normal, so it seems to be bug with subversion plugin of eclipse juno.